# Returning fields from navigation properties as a string from a list of objects in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a person class

```
public class Person 
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public ICollection<Roles> roles { get; set; }
}
```

and a roles class

public class Roles 
    {
    public string LongName { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int Division { get; set; }
    }

and in the controller, I'm building a list of SelectListItems like so:

```
List<SelectListItem> agencyList = players
                .Select(p => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = p.LastName + ", " + p.FirstName,
                        Value = Convert.ToString(p.ID)
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Let's say I have two people, John Smith and Ralph Doe.  And some roles, for example:

"Fishmonger","A",1
"Cobbler","B",2
"Ecthymologist","C",3
etc.

The code above will return a list like this:

```
"Smith, John"
"Doe, Ralph"
```

I would like to include the Roles.Shortname in those SelectListItems, so they might say

```
"Smith, John (A,B,C)"
"Doe, Ralph (A,D)"
etc.
```

Is there a way to do that within the .Select(), or do I need to create a foreach() loop and iterate through all the people and build the SelectListItems that way?

Comment: What is a role's short name? Is it a letter such as `A` or `D`?,

Answer (score 1):

If you have list of players loaded to memory you should be able to create the output you desire using the following code:

```
.Select(p => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = p.LastName + ", " + p.FirstName 
        + "(" + String.Join(", ", p.Roles.Select(role=>role.ShortName)) + ")",
    Value = Convert.ToString(p.ID)
})
```

In this case you start as previously, but then you use function [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) to join these strings.

For better readability and potentially slightly better performance you can use `string.Format`:

```
Text = string.Format("{0}, {1} ({2})", p.LastName, p.FirstName,
    String.Join(", ", p.Roles.Select(role=>role.ShortName))
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted.